# Creating Instances Scaled to Mesh Islands

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a planar mesh where I'm selecting faces to keep based on an image texture:

[image: The mesh, after the faces have been discarded by the image filter]

I want to instance cylinders on each mesh island, and I'd like the radius of the cylinders to be scaled based on the size of the island itself. Currently, I'm using `Face Neighbors` to separate out all of the single face islands, and the diagonal connections, so that all that remains are the islands that need some sort of scaling.

I've been able to take the islands and reduce them to just an edge boundary, which I made into n-gons with `Mesh to Curve` and `Fill Curve`. The problem is that when I try to capture the face area of the n-gons and use that to scale the instances, it outputs an area value of 0 for all of those faces, so the resulting cylinders are all the same size. I'm not sure why this is happening.

[image: The mesh with n-gons where I need the points. The Face Area node isn't giving me anything useful here.]

I'm open to other solutions, but this has been the one that I've gotten closest with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer.

[image]

- First I'm creating a local indies of the faces per island, taking the average position of the island, and the total face area per island.
- Then I convert the **Faces** to points
- I use the local index to turn only a single face per island into a point, I use the average position as that point's position, and the total face area per island as the point radius.
- Lastly I instance cylinders on those points and use the Radius (which is the total face area) as the xy scale.

---

Alternatively you can use the same strategy you did, and use the face count of the island instead of the face area.

[image]

you could also divide it by the grid resolution to give you a more consistent result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out:

I used `Accumulate Field` to count the number of faces per island, then set the ID of each of the whole geometry according to this number, followed by a `Merge by Distance` set to "Connected Only" to make every island into one vertex. I used `Mesh to Points` and ended up with a bunch of points that have an id that I could then use as a scaling factor later, also using `Map Range` with the id's `Attribute Statistic` to let me choose the appropriate scale.
[image: First half of geometry nodes.]

[image: Second half of geometry nodes.]

[image: The result in the viewport.]

There's still tweaking to do but at its basic level it works!

Comment: Map Range "From Min" probably should be `1`, otherwise no cylinder will have the "Minimum Star Size". Also 3 nitpicks: 1) you don't need to capture your mesh island index, because you don't modify it in any way before it's used, 2) "Mesh to Points" and "Set Point Radius" are redundant (you can remove them), 3) the entire scaling branch can be connected to the "Instance on Points: Scale" if you set Attribute Statistic to use the point domain. All in all, good job 

Comment: One more thing, if you're unhappy with the positions of the cylinders, because you want an average position of faces, not an average position of vertices (subtle difference, I know), then consider using another accumulate field node to sum up all positions, divide that by the number of faces per island, move all points there, then merge by distance.

Comment: Nice ID trick you used